# Second do function by press button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why function dont want write to the demo pragraph for second press button with other value?

```js
function check(x){
 if (x == 0,100) {return 1;}
 else { return 25;};
}
function test2() {
  var y,input;
  input = document.getElementById("input2").value;
  y = check(input);
  $("#demo2").html( y );
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="input2">
<button id="but" onclick ="test2()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo2"></p>
```

Comment: what this (if (x == 0,100) ) is doing?

Comment: yes, console:Unexpected token if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your check() function always return 1 and your p is overwritten each time you press the button.

what do you want to achieve in your if() ?

**EDIT**

Change your if to

```
if (x != '' && (x == 0 || x == 100))
```

Comment: When i write to the input 0 or 100 function check return 1 to y. When i write to the input other number function return 25 to y. After y is wrtite to demo2 paragraph.